# Query based on contain for Date

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am trying to view the query based on months and years selected:

I have already got selected date which is as declared (    //dateselectedStr = "2016-11"
)

and the storing date in the online database contain the updatedAt the same 2016-11, how can i search the query based on having .contain ? This is my trails

```
query.order(byDescending: "updatedAt")
if PFUser.current() != nil {


query.whereKey(CARD_UPDATED_AT, contains: dateselectedStr)

query.findObjectsInBackground { (objects, error)-> Void in
    if error == nil {
        self.recipesArray = objects!
        // Reload CollView
        self.recipesCollView.reloadData()
        let counter = (objects!.count)
        print(counter)
        self.title = "\(counter) JOB CARDS"
        self.hideHUD()

        // Hide/show the nothing found Label
        if self.recipesArray.count == 0 { self.nothingFoundLabel.isHidden = false
        } else { self.nothingFoundLabel.isHidden = true }

    } else {
        self.simpleAlert("\(error!.localizedDescription)")
        self.hideHUD()
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, this is the only solution possible

For year 2016,

> updatedAt >= 01-01-2016 & updatedAt <= 31-12-2016

For month January,

> updateAt >= 01-01-2016 & updatedAt <= 31-01-2016

Hope this helps :)